# Windows Server 2008 r2 IIS: can't allow access to file extension in request filtering

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, request-filtering

I have a Windows Server 2008 r2 installation with configured FTP and IIS.

If I upload through FTP two files: "test.txt" and "test.abc" and then try to access these files through HTTP, then I can access only test.txt - then trying to access test.abc. results in 404.

I found this link: [File Name Extensions](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions)

I followed the instructions to edit the Request Filtering. And denying works - if I set to deny ".txt" extension, then trying to access test.txt results in the same 404 error. But I don't manage to allow ".abc", adding it as allowed extension doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there some other place where I need to make changes too in order to be able to access the file through HTTP? If I uninstall "Request Filtering", will then all files be accessible through HTTP?

---

Now I removed Request Filtering altogether and rebooted the server - but without change - accessing the ".abc" file still gives 404.
I'm connecting to this server through a VPN tunnel. Is it possible that VPN filters out such requests and returns 404 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but not quite right.  IIS will respond with 404 for any file that doesn't have a registered MIME Type.  Here's how to fix it:

- Open IIS Manager
- Select the Server, Site, or Application that you want to add the mime type to
- In the IIS sub-section, open the MIME Types feature
- Add the extension for your ".abc" file with an appropriate mime type (for whatever type of file it actually is).

Here is the relevant documentation:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap